# Why do proportionality constants come on only one side?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, mathematics

We know that voltage is directly proportional to current. Then if we change proportionality to equality, we get $V=IR$. Why not $I=RV$??

Comment: You can write $I = RV$, but then the letter $R$ there is no longer the resistance, but the conductance. This will confuse everybody else.

Comment: Conductance is usually denoted $G$,not that it is a widespread symbol, so an acceptable form of Ohm's law is $I=GV$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't come only on one side. Suppose I define a new pair of constants $K_1$ and $K_2$, which obey:

$$R = \frac{K_1}{K_2}$$

Then I can write:

$$K_2V=K_1I$$

And I have a constant on both sides. For convenience, we usually just collect any constant values into a single constant, give it a name, ideally an intuitive one, and put it on one side. Which side is mostly just up to the preference of whoever is defining the relation.